# Type "delete" to confirm deleting mysql entry

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've built a system using conditional PHP and MySQL, for the most part the delete query is simple but to cut down on redundancy I've implemented an undo feature so I don't have to ask you every time if you really want to delete an item.

But I have 1 entry in particular that users are not really supposed to delete. I'm faced with the typical popup messages, which are common and easy to implement but I'm reaching out because I would like to go 1 step beyond that.

I would like to have a modal (using bootstrap 3) come up and force the user to type the word "delete" in order to really delete the entry from the database. I have a working query to delete the item, but my road block is confirming that they typed delete correctly without looking into lower or upper case.

So with that in mind, they could type the following "delete", "Delete", "DELETE", "DeLeTe" or anything in between and it would work just fine but if they type anything other than that, it would spit out an error and cancel out the query execution.

I have not explored javascript because I don't really know much to begin with. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Whatever the user typed, convert it to lowercase/uppercase then compare to `delete`/`DELETE`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strtolower($_POST['delete_confirm']) === 'delete') {
    //delete
} else {
    //error
}
```

Converts the input to all lowercase, then you can check if it equals "delete".

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the user typed, convert it to `lowercase`/`uppercase` then compare to `delete`/`DELETE`. Here's an example:

```js
function validate() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("someInput");
  var loweredInput = userInput.value.toLowerCase();
  if (loweredInput === "delete") {
    alert("SAME");
  } else {
    alert("NOT SAME");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="someInput" type="text" />
<button id="btnValidate" type="button" onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general idea you need to implement to remove the burden from the user.

Using JS

```
$mystrFromInput = "DELETE";
if($mystrFromInput.toUpperCase() === "DELETE") deleteStuff();
```

Using PHP

```
$mystrFromInput = "DELETE";
if(strtoupper($mystrFromInput) === "DELETE") deleteStuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the shortest solution in PHP, I think:

```
if (strcasecmp($_POST['delete_confirm'],'delete')) //delete
```